# use if statment in datagrid view

Tags: visual-studio-2013

i want to add i want to add column name Class they continue data as word or excel or access or internet or windows by condtion conditon ex: coulmn1 "المجموة النوعية" = وظائف كتابية and column2 الوظيفة = كاتب شئون معاهد and column3 word = yes and column4 excel = no and coulmn5 windows = yes and column6 access = no then center image description hereoulmn class = excel

name Class they contine data as word or excel or access or internet or windows by condtion 
conditon ex: coulmn1 "المجموة النوعية" = وظائف كتابية  and column2 الوظيفة = كاتب شئون معاهد and coulmn 3 word = yes and coulmn4 excel = no and coulmn5 windows = yes and coulmn6 access = no
**then** c[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMvUW.jpg)oulmn class = excel

Comment: In order to get more help, you should write your question completely in English.

Comment: This isn't actually a question.  What is it you would like to know?  How to create a datagrid view, or how to add columns or something else?

Comment: no i want to add last column that continue data by condition

Comment: ex: if column 1 = ... and column 2= --- and column 3=--- then the last column  = ---

Comment: please first see my image and the question 
i want to add last column that continue data by condition  mins ago   edit   
     
**example** : if column 1 =  and column 2= --- and column 3=--- then the last column = ---